# Why do we reset/clear at 1010 (10) when designing a BCD Ripple Counter

Tags: logic-gates, flipflop, counter, shift-register, ripple-counter

Shouldn't we reset at 9, I believe that a decade counter goes as follows '0->1->2->3...->8->9->0" or at least that's how its done for synchronous BCD counters.

Comment: We need to see the actual code or logic. (My guess is that you have an asynchronous reset on 10, which is different from a synchronous counter where you switch to zero on 9.)

Comment: I thought that since both are known as 'decade counters' they both operate on the same logic, which is go back to '0' after reaching '9', this way if one would be connected to a display it would show the sequence '0->1->2->3...->8->9->0'

Comment: Because it's a ripple counter not a synchronous design. In a synchronous counter you would generate a "load 0" or "reset to 0" signal when the counter reached 9, and it would be done on the NEXT clock edge. In a ripple counter it happens immediately, so you wait till the counter reaches 10 then reset it immediately.

Comment: In other words, for less than maybe 50 ns the ripple counter will have actually a count of ten on its output.

Comment: @BrianDrummond that's exactly the answer I needed, would you mind writing this as an answer so I can accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a ripple counter not a synchronous design.

In a synchronous counter you would generate a "load 0" or "reset to 0" signal when the counter reached 9, and it would be done on the NEXT clock edge.

In a ripple counter it happens immediately, so you wait till the counter reaches 10 then reset it immediately. The counter actually reaches 10 - but only for a few nanoseconds before clearing. In the context of a ripple counter, this is acceptable; glitches and momentarily incorrect outputs are part of their operation.